# How to convert an int64 into a datetime?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the column Year (type: int64) into a date type so that I can use the Groupby function to group by decade.

I'm using the following code to convert the datatype:

```
import datetime as dt
crime["Date"]=pd.TimedeltaIndex(crime["Year"], unit='d')+dt.datetime(1960,1,1)
crime[["Year","Date"]].head(10)
```

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrxoM.png)

The date it is returning to me is not correct - it isn't starting at the correct year and the day is increasing by the rows.

I want the year to start at 1960, and for each row the year to increase by 1.

I tried substituting `unit='d'` in the code above with `unit='y'` and I get the following result:

```
Value Error: Units 'M' and 'Y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta value durations.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the column in the following way:

```
crime['Date'] = crime['Year'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime(1960 + x,1,1))
```

Comment: Ah...I see.  I missed that `crime['Year']` was already an incremental value from 1960.  If that's the case, then yes, this is your solution me thinks.

Answer (score 1):

I think @kate's answer is what you want.  I wrote my answer before that one came along.  I thought my answer might still be worth something to explain why `unit='y'` isn't supported, and why `unit='d'` isn't working for you either...

I wouldn't think this would be right:

```
TimedeltaIndex(crime["Year"], unit='d')
```

as I expect this to be interpreting your year count as a count of days.  If you can't use `unit='y'`, then maybe there's a good reason for that.  Maybe that is because years don't always have the same number of days in them, and so specifying a number of years is ambiguous in terms of the number of days that equates to.  You have to add any count of years to an actual year for it to make exact sense.

The same holds true, even moreso, for months, since months have a variety of day counts, so you can have no idea what a timedelta in months really means.

Comment: Nicely explained :)